# Dump sql queries with Laravel/Lumen DB facade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1, lumen

I am using Lumen (latest version as on time), and running some database queries using `DB:insert()` method.

```
$insert = DB:insert('insert into sales (sale_number, sale_value, time) values (?,?,?)',[$sale_number, $sale_value, Carbon::now()]);
```

For some reason, the insert isn't working, and the screen shows blank.

var_dump($insert) returns false

I've added a listener in the App service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) {
            echo 'SQL: '.$sql;
            var_dump( $bindings);

        });
    }
}
```

However, it echoes

```
SQL: insert into sales (sale_number, sale_value, time) values (?,?,?)
array();
```

`DB::getQueryLog();` also dumps the query and bindings separately.

How I can get a compiled query?

Comment: Do you have any messages in your http server log or app log?

Comment: if I use Log::info('Error : '.$insert) the it is displaying in lumen.log  as lumen.INFO: Error :   , but I didn't get any error message

Comment: Try wrapping your insert with a `try { ... } catch` block and inspect any exception that is thrown.

Comment: Thanks JRD. Found the issue using exceptional handling fixed

Answer (score -1):

You can't.

PDO does not give you that option. All frameworks and libraries struggle with that.

If you're on unix and have mysql running locally you can run:

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

This will output the queries as they run on mysql.

If you aren't running unix, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM  mysql.general_log  LIMIT 10;
```

To output the last 10 queries ran on mysql. Still, not available through PDO.Sorry =(